# graph - Dijkstra for The Single-Source Longest Path

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, dijkstra

Ok, I posted this question because of this exercise:

> Can we modify Dijkstra’s algorithm to solve the single-source longest path problem by changing minimum to maximum? If so, then prove your algorithm correct. If not, then provide a counterexample.

For this exercise or all things related to Dijkstra's algorithm, **I assume there are no negative weights in the graph**. Otherwise, it makes not much sense, as even for shortest path problem, Dijkstra can't work properly if negative edge exists.

---

Ok, my intuition answered it for me:

Yes, I think it can be modified.

I just

1. initialise distance array to MININT
2. change `distance[w] > distance[v]+weight` to `distance[w] < distance[v]+weight`

---

Then I did some research to verify my answer. I found this post:

[Longest path between from a source to certain nodes in a DAG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598174/longest-path-between-from-a-source-to-certain-nodes-in-a-dag)

First I thought my answer was wrong because of the post above. But I found that maybe the answer in the post above is wrong. It mixed up **The Single-Source Longest Path Problem** with **The Longest Path Problem**.

Also in wiki of [Bellman–Ford algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm), it said correctly :

> The Bellman–Ford algorithm computes single-source shortest paths in a weighted digraph. **For graphs with only non-negative edge weights, the faster Dijkstra's algorithm also solves the problem**. Thus, Bellman–Ford is used primarily for graphs with negative edge weights.

So I think my answer is correct, right? 
Dijkstra can really be *The Single-Source* Longest Path Problem and my modifications are also correct, right?

Comment: @Kristo, can you please have a look?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, we cannot<sup>1</sup> - or at the very least, no polynomial reduction/modification is known - [longest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) is [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard), while dijkstra runs in polynomial time!

If we can find a modfication to dijsktra to answer longest-path problem in polynomial time, we can derive `P=NP`

> If not, then provide a counterexample.

This is very bad task. The counter example can provide a specific modification is wrong, while there could be a different modification that is OK.

The truth is we do not know if longest-path problem is solveable in polynomial time or not, but the general assumption is - it is not.

---

regarding just changing the relaxation step:

```
        A
       / \
      1   2
     /     \
    B<--1---C
edges are (A,B),(A,C),(C,B)
```

dijkstra from A will first pick B, and then B is never reachable - because it is out of the set of `distances`.

At the very least, one will have also to change min heap into max heap, but it will have a different counter-example why it fails.

---

(1) probably, maybe if P=NP it is possible, but it is very unlikely.

Comment: amit, this is what I was talking about in my question. I think Longest Path problem is different from Single sourced Longest Path problem. In `Longest Path problem`, we need to find the single longest path in the whole graph. But in my question above, `single sourced` means we are given a vertex S, then find out which path is longest oriented from S. They are different problems, right?

Comment: ah, ok, I think I made a mistake. If single sourced longest path problem can be solved, then we just for each vertex we do single-source longest path, then compare them all, then solve the longest path problem. This is not possible as the longest path problem is NP. ok, I guess what I thought wrong.

Comment: can you please possibly use simplest words to describe why longest path problem can't be solved if I replace MIN with MAX in Dijkstra?

Comment: @JacksonTale: The idea behind dijkstra's algorithm is doing local relaxation. Note that in dijkstra's algorithm, when a node with minimal distance is picked and removed from the list of nodes, it is OK, we will never need to modify it again, while for the max problem - it is not true.

Comment: @Evgeny Kluev's answer is totally different. who I should trust? :D

Comment: @JacksonTale: Evgeny's answer makes different assumption then stated in the question. If you can control the input to have only negative weights - Evgeny's answer is correct, there is a simple reduction to shortest weight problem. However, if the input is as stated in the question - no negative weights, the problem is NP-Hard.

Comment: Yeah I also commented on his answer. Thanks for answering my answer for the 3rd time. I am self learning algorithms and will put every excise I can't solve in stackoverflow, lol, this is my plan. Hope you can help me further in the future.

Comment: what if the graph is DAG with all positive edges? or a AG with all positive edges?

Comment: @JacksonTale in DAG there are at most O(n^2) paths, so this problem is much easier then the general case, and could be solved polynomially.

Comment: Can I use or modify Dijkstra, I mean for DAG with all positive edges

Comment: @JacksonTale: I believe a modification exist, but I cannot think of it at the moment. As you already know however, I prefer reducing problems to existing algorithms instead of modifying algorithms. In this case, I'd create a new weight function `w'(e) = -w(e)`, and invoke Bellman Ford with `w'`. Since the graph is a DAG, there are no cycles, and specifically no negative cycles, and BF will return the shortest path according to `w'`, which is the longest path according to `w`! What do you think? Is that fits your problem as well?

Comment: Yes, I think you are right and your idea of reducing problem or transforming problem is always best and I agree.

Comment: This answer is not accurate. It is correct that in general, Dijkstra cannot be used for finding the longest path, but there is  a subset of graphs for which Dijkstra can find the longest path: If all edges on the given graph `G` are non-positive, one can transform `G` to `-G` by negating all edges . In this case the shortest path found by Dijkstra in `-G` corresponds to the longest path in `G`

Comment: @Ari The answer is in context of the question, which asks for a general graph. Here are some more cases where it may work: (1) [Only edges out of the source are negative.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/124344/19176) (2) Graph has no edges (3) graph is a tree. But the question is NOT about a special subclass of graphs, this restriction is not introduced to the question, and I saw no reason to address this specifically (and not, say, it works on trees)

Comment: @amit: There are two things to consider: The classic shortest path Dijkstra algorithm only works on graphs with non-negative edges, not all graphs, so the problem is not general to begin with. Similarly, one can use Dijkstra for finding the longest path by using `-G` for graphs with non-positive edges. So the two cases are symmetrical and comparable. Secondly, finding the longest path is not actually NP-Complete. What is famously known as NP-complete is finding the `simple` shortest path which has created a lot of confusion:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/53399638/1383356

Comment: Non simple longest path is not defined, similar to BF negative cycle, if you have a positive cycle, you can do "one more loop" and get a longer path between two points.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, we can. And your answer is almost correct. Except one thing.

You assume **no negative weights**. In this case Dijkstra's algorithm cannot find longest path.

But if you assume **only negative weights**, you can easily find the longest path. To prove correctness, just take absolute values of all weights and you get exactly the usual Dijkstra's algorithm with positive weights.

Comment: I think your answer is doing a trick. If I assume only negative weights, the longest path is like `shortest path in all positive weights`. I don't think it is what the excise is seeking for.

Comment: @JacksonTale, yes, this is just a trick. But it's not clear from the excise text, what does it mean. Otherwise, amit's answer is very good.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I guess what the excise really mean is for the real longest path problem. My bad to add such an assumption.

Comment: The idea of using Dijkstra's for non-positive weights is very interesting. Especially, when we're required to find longest path for a graph G with all edges of -ve or zero weights, then it's wiser to apply Dijkstra's rather than Bellman-Ford's on the transformed grapgh G' =(-G) in order to achieve better run-time.

Answer (score 0):

It works in directed acyclic graphs but not in cyclic graphs. Since the path will back track and there is no way of avoiding that in dijkstra's algo

Comment: Also doesn't work in DAG's, as explained in amit's answer.