# Why finding the longest path in a graph is NP-hard

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

This [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) mentions:

> A longest path between two given vertices s and t in a weighted graph
>   G is the same thing as a shortest path in a graph −G derived from G by
>   changing every weight to its negation. Therefore, if shortest paths
>   can be found in −G, then longest paths can also be found in G.

So why is finding the longest path an NP-hard problem if this transformation can reduce it to the shortest path problem?

After the transformation, we have have these cases:

- `-G` has a negative cycle, in which case the shortest path in `-G` cannot be found
- `-G` does not have a negative cycle, in which case Floy-Warshall or Bellman-Ford algorithm can find the shortest path in `-G` in polynomial time

**Questions:**

1. Is it correct to say if there is no negative cycle, the problem of finding longest path is not NP-hard?
2. Is it correct to say in the presence of negative cycles, there is still a longest `simple path` between nodes which is NP-hard to be found?
3. If so, is it more accurate to say finding the longest **simple** path in a graph is NP-hard?
4. If so, because of `-G` transformation is it also correct to say that finding the shortest **simple** path in a graph is also NP-hard?

**Edit**

This link explains the confusion about longest path problem in more details:
https://hackernoon.com/shortest-and-longest-path-algorithms-job-interview-cheatsheet-2adc8e18869

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The confusion here is that the Longest Path Problem generally asks for the longest *simple* path, i.e., the longest path without repeated vertices. For this reason, it can be reduced to the Hamiltonian Path problem, which is known to be NP-hard.

Bellman-Ford and similar algorithms, on the other hand, compute the shortest path in a graph (note: without *simple*), i.e. vertices can be repeated.

So your four questions:

1. No. If there is a negative cycle in `-G`, a longest path does not exist at all in `G`, because you can just continue walking around the cycle forever. A longest `simple` path might still exist, but with or without negative cycle, the problem can be reduced to Hamiltonian Path and is therefore still NP-hard.
2. Indeed! (If the graph is undirected.)
3. Yup
4. Yup

Comment: So is it correct to say finding the shortest simple path is NP-hard?

Comment: I added answers to your 4 questions (to the best of my knowledge). Interesting (and indeed confusing) topic; I hope I'm not failing to see something :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It confirms my understanding, but I am surprised that I never saw it anywhere that finding the shortest simple path is NP-hard!

Comment: Well the proof follows quite easily from your own reasoning :) The shortest simple path problem can be reduced to the longest simple path problem (by graph negation), and then the longest simple path problem can be reduced to Hamiltonian Path problem by simply having all edges have weight 1. Thus NP-hard. I suppose the shortest simple path problem when allowing negative edges is a little special... perhaps why neither you nor me have heard about it. :)

Comment: Yes, it is fascinating that we don't hear about the shortest simple path problem often although the equivalent longest simple path problem is famously known as an NP-hard problem. I just found this other post that states the proof: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17462/finding-the-shortest-path-in-the-presence-of-negative-cycles

Answer (score 1):

- First, Longest-path problem is in general NP-Hard (in fact NP-Complete) even
  when there is no negative edges. I have tried to prove it from
  basics, [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/137129/62634); also for the proof of NP-complete, you might like to
  check this [one](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/121265/62634).
- Second, for various categories of Graphs, scientists    have come up
  with polynomial time solution to this. DAG, and tree are two such
  kinds.
- Third, for DAG, while one option is to find    shortest    distance
  in a transformed graph, -G (this is mentioned in    Sedgewick    book,
  4th Ed), there is also another alternate, see    [here](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/%7Echeung/Courses/171/Syllabus/11-Graph/Docs/longest-path-in-dag.pdf).    Both
  run in theta(E+V) time.
- Finally, for answers to your questions 1 thru 3, I'll stick to
  [Berthur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53399638/1029599). But for your question 4, note that we do not do a
  transformation like -G, for any arbitrary graph G. If we at all do so, then
  it is a DAG. In fact, we often prove longest-path problem as NPC by referring to
  Hamiltonian path - which has nothing to do with weights, let alone negative
  weights.