# graph - Modifications to Dijkstra algorithm to find single source longest path

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, dijkstra

Let `G = (V,E)` be a directed graph with no positive length cycles. Modifying Dijkstra algorithm as follow, with `s` the source:

1. Initialize `d(s) = 0`, `d(v) = int_min` for all `v in V \ {s}`.
2. In each iteration, choose a node `u` with maximum `d(u)`.
3. Redefine the tentative distance as: if `d(v) < d(u) + c(uv)` then `d(v) := d(u) + c(uv)`.

Is this a correct algorithm to find the length of the longest path in `G` starting from `s` ? If not, give a counter example. I have seen a similar answer to this question such as this one [graph - Dijkstra for The Single-Source Longest Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462736/graph-dijkstra-for-the-single-source-longest-path) but there is no appropriate counter example provided that contradicts the algorithm. Since most of the answers from other (somewhat) similar questions is the algorithm is incorrect, I am inclined to think the same but could not find a counter example.

Comment: The basic premise of Dijkstra is that nodes may be visited many times, but only explored once. That premise is violated by the proposed changes. After the first iteration, only the nodes connected directly to `s` are eligible to be explored. But each one of those nodes could be visited later with a longer distance, resulting in the aforementioned violation of the basic premise.

Comment: @user3386109 can you provide an example of the violation ?

Comment: @ endeavor Looks like JackRaBeat saw your comment before I did. That's pretty much what my example would have looked like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want example of violation you should give a proper definition of your dijkstra algorithms, for now lets use the wiki definition:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

and our counter example will be this graph:
[image]

notice that you'll get into vertice 6 way before you'll get into vertice 5 so eventually the algorithm will won't repeat vertice 6 after it got into it as mention here:

> When we are done considering all of the unvisited neighbors of the current node, mark the current node as visited and remove it from the unvisited set. A visited node will never be checked again (this is valid and optimal in connection with the behavior in step 6.

as you can see the idea beneath dijkstra is when you explore a node you won't need to explore never again and in the case of longest path is not true...